# Odd title value for Compose Query button at Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Just visited the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/new) for the first time and noticed that the 'Compose Query' button on top right has an odd `title` value -

```
<a class="youarehere" href="/superuser/query/new" title="item.title">Compose Query</a>
```

It might be intentional but it seemed a bit strange to me that `item.title` would be the title value of that button. Just wanted to report it.

Comment: [More meta please](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17036050/scr181.png) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dispatched an emergency search party which promptly found [the `@` that was missing](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=08c677c1edcddf19362df6b555b4068693998a6a) from the template there. Fixed once waffles pulls and redeploys.

Comment: Way to go Captain Stone. :)